# Right inverse of an under-determined linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, linear-programming, matrix-calculus

I am looking at a slides from a neural network class and there is a brief discussion on the inverse of an over-determined and under-determined system. I understood the left inverse of an over-determined system. However, I am confused on one part of the inverse of the under-determined system.

The system is:

$b=Ax$

Let A be an mxn matrix with full row rank r=m. The matrix $AA^T$ is an $m\times m$ matrix. This is a non-singular symmetric matrix and the inverse exists. Hence,

$(AA^T)^{-1}AA^T = I$

Now, the slides jump to this equation:

$(AA^T)^{-1}A^TAx=(AA^T)^{-1}A^Tb$ // I don't understand how this is possible when the dimensions don't match

and from there it says it follows:

$x=A^T(AA^T)^{-1}b=A^+b$ // I don't understand how it gets to this part as well.

and finally:

$A^{-1}_{right\ inverse}=A^+=A^T(AA^T)^{-1}$

Can you help me clarify the steps?

Comment: You’re right: those expressions don’t make sense. It looks as if whoever created those slides incorrectly copied and pasted the left inverse derivation slide. Are these slides accessible somewhere?

Comment: No they are not available publicly.
Can you show me how to derive the inverse of an undetermined system with full row rank r=m?